# R missing fonts

Tags: r, cairo, pango

I just built R 3.3.1 using spack (LLNL package manager).

A quick test of demo turned an issue with font displays.

demo(Hershey) produces:
[image]

Building R pulled in pango/1.40.1 and cairo/1.14.0
among many others.

I have been told that R font management is done through pango and/or cairo.
Is there a compatibility issue that I am encountering?

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved.

I did the following:

spack stage cairo@1.14.0
spack stage pango@1.40.1

spack edit R
add
    version('3.3.2', '2437014ef40641cdc9673e89c040b7a8')

spack edit fontconfig

```
#   def configure_args(self):
#       font_path = join_path(self.spec['font-util'].prefix, 'share', 'fonts')

#       return ["--prefix={0}".format(self.prefix),
#               "--enable-libxml2",
#               "--disable-docs",
#               "--with-default-fonts={0}".format(font_path)]

    def configure_args(self):
        args = ["--prefix=%s" % prefix,
                "--enable-libxml2",
                "--disable-docs"]
        return args
```

spack install R@3.3.2 %gcc@6.2.0

edit
remove "make('check') in pixman

==> Successfully installed R
  Fetch: 15.34s.  Build: 8m 3.89s.  Total: 8m 19.23s.